# How do I stop html displaying on front end?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have:

```
br/label
```

and

```
<br><label>,hone<label>
```

displaying on the front end of my site.

It's part of a plugin and I can't locate it in the source code, which is anyway encrypted.

Is there a directive to hide it?

Comment: We need some more information about your code

Comment: It's displaying on mobile dialing screen and mobile and maps, both through through a button. But can you hide html, as you can with css? Both 'location' and 'phone' are effected by labels. Specifically </br><label>Phone:<label/> And:  </br><label>Location:<label/>

Comment: You have all the slashes in the wrong places in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:none` on a parent element.

EDIT: Based on your comments, it's an error in your HTML. Check these lines of codes in your HTML:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=:<br/><label>Location:</label> London, UK"> 
  <div class="location"><br/><label>Location:</label> London, UK</div>
</a>
```

There is HTML injected into the URL. You have to remove that. If the query URL is wrong, you can't remove it from the Google Maps. Your HTML should be something like

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/London"> 
  <div class="location"><br/>
    <label>Location: London, UK</label> 
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Hiding parent element will hide parent element-don't want that. Can I use before/after css?

Comment: Maybe a CSS like 
`br {
  label {
    display: none;
  }
}`
It's a hack, but if you really cannot influence the HTML you get it can work.

Comment: You're right sorry that was SCSS :) It should work this way: 
`br label { display: none; }` Or more precisely `br > label { display: none; }`

Comment: I really wanted it to work, but it didn't. Any other ideas? When i click location, I've got this displaying in Google maps when it searched for 'London UK' : 'br/  label Location: /label  London, UK'

Comment: The map thinks it's searching for a place called ': br/  label Location: /label  London, UK'

Comment: Whereas i want to hide everything except 'London, UK'

Comment: Otherwise maps gets confused

Comment: I need more information. Do you use Google API? Do you call anything else before? Can you post your problem on StackBlitz?

Comment: Im just a novice... You can view html here:https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/14/nicos-cleaning-service/london/uk/business-advert/

Comment: It's affected by $adcontactphone

Comment: But you won't find $adcontactphone in view-source

Comment: Also influenced by '$location.' This contains generic location plus individual location for each posting...Google searches for specific listing location. Im guessing within $location is contained 'br label'

Comment: There is no way in HTML to have a label in a br, so `br label {..}` will not accomplish anything, no matter how you write it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Ill try. But won't your solution just bring up London for every location?

Comment: Yes, but based on your code, that's what it did so far anyway, only with some HTML in the maps search field. What do you want to open in the map?

Comment: You see $location brings up whatever location the user has determined in their advert. Queens, NY, London, Uk, etc. This is where the location of what they have listed is. So a buyer can see on a map where the area is and how far away it is, directions etc. This location setting is automatic. Every time a user places an ad, a button is generated with the location of their product.

Comment: Each ad has a different location, and so html needs to reflect this. It does at the moment....

Comment: If I change it to your version, this will change the button destination to search London every time. Now it searches according to the location the user has listed, which is what I want. So the question is, how do I keep that function, but get rid of all the 'br label....' stuff

Comment: @mrlister so what do I do? Thanks

Comment: @user11101457 Your original question was specifically about how to remove the unwanted HTML being displayed on the page. It looks like you have expanded that into searching for locations which is beyond the scope of your original question. If you need help on this, please start new question instead.